# Virtual Machine installation

Tags: system-installation, virtualization

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 for use in a virtual machine. I seem to need a .iso file in order to boot the OS, but when I downloaded it, it went straight to a DVD drive F: that isn't actually a CD or a drive on my laptop. I can view the files that I assume are the OS but nothing in there is a .iso file. I can't use the drive to boot the OS on VMware. Not sure what to do here, would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .iso you downloaded is a file much like a zip archive.

You can use it with virtualbox to boot and install Ubuntu.

Windows manages or recognizes the file in various ways, in your case it recognized it as an .iso and mounted it with some sort of tool to create a virtual drive F: , daemon tools ?

Unmount or eject F: and use the .iso file in Virtualbox.

See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-mount-or-unmount-iso-images-windows-10 or similar for further information.

Comment: "Ejecting" the disk worked. I had tried it before but the resulting file location of the .iso was not where I expected. A system search led me to it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Panther here. In virtual box and VMWare there is a setting that allows you to open the ISO to the VM. I believe their respective wizards actually prompt for either a physical disc or a image file (ISO, IMG, etc). So as far as I'm aware you wouldn't need to open it on the host system.